# What should be on-topic for Law.SE?

Tags: discussion

#### <strike>As you can see, the [/help/on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page isn't filled in yet</strike>.

#### The [/help/on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page has now been updated with the below text.

We've been up and running long enough that we've developed a sense of questions that are, and aren't on-topic for the site.

Here are some of the key discussions and points that have been made:

- **Dealing with lawyers should be on topic**
  [Should questions asking about dealing with lawyers (but not about the law itself) be on-topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-questions-asking-about-dealing-with-lawyers-but-not-about-the-law-itself)
- **Hypotheticals should be on-topic**
  [Are hypothetical application of the law questions on topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-hypothetical-application-of-the-law-questions-on-topic)
  [Are hypotheticals on topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/are-hypotheticals-on-topic)
- **Historical legal questions should be on-topic**
  [Do we want to allow historical legal questions?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/do-we-want-to-allow-historical-legal-questions)
- **Questions about quasi-judicial bodies should be on-topic**
  [Quasi-judicial bodies on topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/quasi-judicial-bodies-on-topic)
- **Questions that ask for legal advice should be off-topic**, at least as too localised.
  [What is our stance on questions that are very clearly legal advice?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-that-are-very-clearly-legal-advice)
  <sup>[What is our stance on questions that are very clearly legal advice?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-that-are-very-clearly-legal-advice#comment286_169) a comment on an answer, suggesting how one can make a specific question general.</sup>

---

#### <strike>With all of that in mind, here's what we're proposing for our **on-topic** page</strike>

#### This is now live on the page:

> Law Stack Exchange is for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law.
>
> The best questions are those that have [specific answers](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/); Law Stack Exchange is not a general discussion forum. In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals
>
> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are [**off-topic**](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-should-be-on-topic-for-law-se) for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.
>
> [Please look around](https://law.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Law Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.
>
> For more help, see "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)"

---

#### What should be different? What should be in there, but isn't? What *shouldn't* be in there, but is?

- We can modify this later through discussion and consensus, if we feel that things should/shouldn't be on-topic.
- Please also note that, if we adopt this as our on-topic page, we will add a corresponding custom off-topic reason, to reflect the fact that legal advice questions are off-topic. The wording will likely be:

  > Questions that ask for *specific legal advice* are off topic. See [this meta post].

  **This off-topic close reason is now live**

  We'll update a meta post with guidelines on rewriting a specific legal advice question and turning it into a general information question.

> **Important:** If there's no slew of criticism on this post, then we will interpret this as assent. Despite [Warnock's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warnock's_dilemma), there's no way for us to *force* everyone to contribute to, and vote on, this proposal.
>   **If you disagree** with any part of this, please post a comment (or an answer, if your disagreement is lengthy/substantial. We want to discuss any issues about this, and **this is your chance to help shape the direction the site will take**. You can also ping any of the mods in chat and we will be happy to discuss it there.

Comment: I like it. Looks like the only thing we're explicitly saying *no* to is legal advice. And, we can change this frequently as we learn throughout the beta, right?

Comment: @nomenagentis Absolutely. The main reason that we're saying no to legal advice is largely for the reasons that [Andrew outlined](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/a/169/58), as we definitely don't want to drive away lawyers. _If_ there's a way to reconcile that desire with one to provide help to those who need it - perhaps later on through an aggressive editing policy where we encourage editing questions so that they _don't ask for legal advice_ and can be answered and useful - then we can definitely edit it.

Comment: @nomenagentis also see Andrew's [comment](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-that-are-very-clearly-legal-advice#comment286_169) on that answer, that basically says "you can ask things if they're general, and here's how". I may incorporate that into the information on this page (which is linked in that paragraph anyway).

Comment: Oh wait, I should say - while we _can_ change it frequently, we will probably want it to be relatively stable, i.e. unless there's some compelling circumstances, e.g. make things off-topic because we're already closing it frequently.

Comment: If legal advice is off-topic, how is answering a question as to whether something is legal on-topic? (Accidentally posted this as an answer. Wups!)

Comment: @bobstro The difference is "Currently the situation is X. Is it legal for me to do Y?" is probably going to be legal advice, whereas "Given a situation X. What legal avenues are available?" is legal information. See [this post](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/a/169/58) and [this comment](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-that-are-very-clearly-legal-advice#comment286_169), not all of which is necessarily going to be codified, but is illuminating. It's generally clear when a question is asking for specific legal advice.

Comment: @jimsug: Should we assume that this is intended to be limited to law within the confines of the United States? If somebody not from this culture is asking about legality of behavior, for example, are other considerations on topic that might relate to the situation? It's the tendency of SE sites to be focused on theory versus practical considerations that I'm trying to come to terms with.

Comment: @bobstro 1) Nope, any kind of law is acceptable. See [this discussion](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-do-we-handle-localization-of-questions-answers) about localisation - in a nutshell though, the custom is: if you don't specify a jurisdiction, answerers will specify the jurisdictions that apply to their answer. 2) If you mean in answers, yes, so long as it primarily provides legal information. But this post relates to questions.

Comment: @bob as for theory vs practical, as mentioned in your other meta post - this is a Law site. And law supervenes on so much of everyday life, if not all, such that it's hard to ignore the practical considerations, which is why I think they're definitely acceptable. But this isn't **Common Sense Stack Exchange**, it's **Law Stack Exchange**. The questions and answers need to reflect that.

Comment: @jimsug: Fair enough, but "common sense" varies significantly by locale. Compare and contrast YouTube (won't promote raw site here) videos of behaviors that are "juvenile pranks" in the UK that wind up with individuals in the same circumstances thrown to the ground, arrested or shot in the US. Some jurisdictions are much more lenient, and I cringe at the thought of a visitor winding up in a world of hurt.

Comment: @bob absolutely - there are jurisdiction tags for that, so if you are specifically asking about the UK, you can indicate it. Yes, there's a chance a passer-by might not see that, but there's always that chance. So I think the compromise is as noted above and in a couple of the answers to your other post - yes, include cautionary tales, but only as a supplement to your substantive legal answer. Unfortunately, we can't protect 100% of people from themselves all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Thanks for the comments and the votes

As of right now, the question has 7 upvotes and no downvotes, and has been viewed 110 times.

#### The [/help/on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is live, with two minor changes since the last vote:

1. The point:

   > - Legal terms, doctrines and theory

   was changed to...

   > - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
2. The link in the paragraph:

   > Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are **off-topic** for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.

   has been changed to point to [this answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10) instead.

#### The custom off-topic reason <strike>will be live shortly</strike> is live now:

> Questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice are off-topic. Please see: [Questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/58).

You can now select this as an off-topic reason. Please have a read through the meta post linked in the close description: [Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/58)

[image: Close dialog with custom off-topic reason]

[image: Close message with custom off-topic reason]

Hopefully, this new close message, and the associated meta post, will help clear things up, and even lead to more questions being asked as people edit questions that might otherwise be/stay closed.

---

Please continue to use Meta to discuss the growth and scope of the site.